# Using ArrayLists as static properties in classes?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

struggling a bit with something. I have built a proof of concept and googled but can't find reason.

1. I am currently trying to use an ArrayList as a static property in a class to store series of entries.  The only problem is that everytime I try add to the Totalentries arraylist I get a nullPointerError.

Would appreciate some guidance as to where I am going wrong?

My Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Competition {
private static ArrayList totalentries;

public Competition(){


}
public void newEntry(){
    totalentries.add("an Entry");
}

}
```

My Test Code:

```
public class testEntries {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Competition myComp=new Competition();
        myComp.newEntry(); //Null Pointer comes here!
        myComp.newEntry();
        myComp.newEntry();
        myComp.newEntry();
        myComp.newEntry();
        myComp.newEntry();

        myComp.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: As noted by many below (let's see how many answer this thread!) -- you never instantiate the ArrayList. Why is it static to begin with?

Comment: This variable shouldn't be static. And its type should be List<String>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never instantiated `totalentries` in your Competition class.

You would need something like:

```
private static ArrayList totalentries = new ArrayList();
```

However, note that I would advise against keeping this "static".  Otherwise, every "Competition" you create will be sharing the same list of entries, which is likely not what you really want.

Also, declare your types using interfaces, than instantiate with types.  You may also want to use Generics here.  So even better (and following standard naming conventions):

```
private List<String> totalEntries = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up.  I have done some more research, and now understand this better! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You never make an `ArrayList`.  Try this:

```
private static ArrayList totalentries = new ArrayList();
```

though it would be better to use generics and get compile-time safety:

```
private static ArrayList<String> totalentries = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Since this list holds properties you wouldn't want it to be replaced so it would be even better if you were to define it like this:

```
private static final ArrayList<String> totalentries = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Really, though, none of these are good ideas because you could have multiple instances of your class changing `totalentries` at the same time.  If that is your intent, that multiple `Competition`s use the one static `totalentries` for storage then you are better off keeping track of that data in a separate class.

If you are only using one `Competition` at a time then remove the `static` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing detailed help! I read up more and now see my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

`totalentries` is not initialized and it points to `null`. Make it like this:

```
private static List<String> totalentries = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The list must be created prior to usage, try 
totalentries = new ArrayList();

You should also use List instead for the totalentries variable instead to allow exchanging te ArrayList with for example LinkedList.